# How to append more than one Number into Binding var

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm new to swift and I'm trying to develop a Velocity Calculator.
Here is my Code:

```
struct VelocityCalc: View {
@State var velocityNumbers1 : [String] = []

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        VStack {
            Text("Headline")
            TextField("e.g., 1, 3, 5, 8,...", text: $velocityNumbers1)
            
            Button {
                print("Button works")
            } label: {
                Text("Tap me")
            }

        }
    }
}
```

What I want to develop is that the User can type in for example: 12, 14, 12, 10, ...
This Numbers needs to be sorted and so on.

Maybe someone can help me with this Issue or give me some advisory for that.

Big thanks for your help :)

Comment: what do you mean by sorted?

Comment: I mean that the array with the Numbers should be sorted from 1, 3, 5, 2 to 1, 2, 3, 5

Comment: So from a user input of `1, 3, 5, 8`, you want to create an Array containing the numbers `1,3,5,8`? You cannot just pass an `Array` to a `TextField` as a `Binding` and expect SwiftUI to magically parse the input as an `Array`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this,

1. Get the numbers as a string
2. Split them using separator(')
3. Convert them into Int and sort

   ```
   struct ContentView: View {
   @State var velocityNumber : String = ""

   var body: some View {
       VStack {
           VStack {
               Text("Headline")
               TextField("e.g., 1, 3, 5, 8,...", text: $velocityNumber)

               Button {
                   let allNumbers = velocityNumber.split(separator: ",").compactMap {
                       Int($0)
                   }

                   print(allNumbers.sorted())
               } label: {
                   Text("Tap me")
               }

           }
       }
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: @aleksandar-nesovanovic Is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 3):

I have seen answers, however what I have found out that when you enter the numbers the way you showed us on your question ex: `2, 1, 5, 9` with `Space` or `WhiteSpace` it won't work as expected so here it is a solution to overcome this problem:

```
@State var velocityNumbers = ""

func reorderTheArray(velocity: String) -> [String] {
    let orderVelocity = velocity.components(separatedBy: ",").compactMap{
        Int($0.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces))
    }
    return orderVelocity.sorted().compactMap {
        String($0)
    }
}

var body: some View {

    VStack {
        Text("Headline")
        TextField("example", text: self.$velocityNumbers)
        
        Button(action: {
            self.velocityNumbers = reorderTheArray(velocity: self.velocityNumbers).joined(separator: ",")
            print(self.velocityNumbers)
            
        }) {
            Text("Reorder")
        }

    }
    
}
```

Now when you click the `Reorder` button, everything will be reordered on your textfield directly.

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

I would see it like this:
First i would take all numbers as a string, then split the string using the separator `","`, then convert all strings to an int array and sort

```
struct VelocityCalc: View {
    @State var velocityNumbers1 : String
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Headline")
                TextField("e.g., 1, 3, 5, 8,...", text: $velocityNumbers1)
                Button {
                    let velocityNumbersArray = velocityNumbers1
                        .components(separatedBy: ",")
                        .map { Int($0)! }.sorted()
                    print(velocityNumbersArray)
                } label: {
                    Text("Tap me")
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it makes more sense to enter one value at a time and use a separate field to display the entered values

```
@State var velocityNumbers : [Int] = []
@State var velocity: String = ""
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        VStack {
            Text("Headline")
            TextField("velocity", text: $velocity)

            Button {
                if let value = Int(velocity) {
                    velocityNumbers.append(value)
                    velocityNumbers.sort()
                }
                velocity = ""
            } label: {
                Text("Add")
            }
            .keyboardShortcut(.defaultAction)

            Divider()

            Text(velocityNumbers.map(String.init).joined(separator: ", "))
        }
    }
}
```